# on inverse image of a set in R^2

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I tried to evaluate a certain double integral by change of variables. When I do that I need to find the preimage of the triangular region bounded by the lines $x=0$, $y=2$ and $x=y$ under the map $x=u(1+v)$, $y=v(1+u)$. To do so I tried to find the pre image of the sides at a time but I am confused in the case of y=2 and x=y. If I can solve the system for u and v interms of x and y,that will be easy but I can't. Please provide your sugestion.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.  Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960)
and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site.
In particular, people will be more willing to help
if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Thanks, you write correctly! I want to use the result to apply change of variables in certain integral.

Comment: I tried to mapp the sides of the triangle but I'm comfused to map the sides y=2 and x=y. If I can solve the given system for u and v in terms of x and y that will br easy but I'm unable to do that.

Comment: Include this into the question body.  Do this before your question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- if $x = 0$, then $u(1+v) = 0$, so *either* $u = 0$ or $v = -1$. So the line $x = 0$ becomes the union of the pair of lines $u = 0$ and $v = -1$
- if $y = 2$, then $v = \frac 2{1 + u}$, a hyperbola with vertical asymptote $u = -1$ and horizontal asymptote $v = 0$.
- Since $x - y = u - v$, if $x = y$ then $u = v$, a line.

[image]

Now you've got to figure out what region between those curves corresponds to your original triangle.

Comment: I just noticed that I plotted $v = 1/(1+u)$ instead of $v = 2/(1+u)$, so the hyperbola is a little off. But it still shows the correct general shape, so I don't think it is worth the effort to fix.

Comment: I should also point out that the $uv$ coordinates actually cover the $xy$ plane *twice*, I said that you need to figure out which region corresponds to your original one, but actually there are two different regions above that correspond to it (it isn't hard to spot them). You could pick either one of them.

Comment: Thank you! I see it and the region in the first quadrant is the corrsponding region.